# I'm receiving maximum call stack size exceeded error on 2 identical defined classes, execept 1 is defining this.name and the other this._name

Tags: javascript

I'm receiving maximum call stack size exceeded error on 2 identical defined classes, execept 1 is defining this.name and the other this._name. What is the difference in the 2 classes that's causing one of them to return a class stack error?

```
class User {

    constructor(name) {
      // invokes the setter
      this.name = name;
    }
  
    get name() {
      return this._name;
    }
  
    set name(value) {
      if (value.length < 4) {
        console.log("Name is too short.");
        return;
      }
      this._name = value;
    }
  
  }
  
  let user = new User("John");
  console.log(user.name); // John
  
  user = new User(""); // Name is too short.
```

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

```
class User {

    constructor(name) {
      // invokes the setter
      this.name = name;
    }
  
    get name() {
      return this.name;
    }
  
    set name(value) {
      if (value.length < 4) {
        console.log("Name is too short.");
        return;
      }
      this.name = value;
    }
  
  }
  
  let user = new User("John");
  console.log(user.name); // John
  
  user = new User(""); // Name is too short.
```

Comment: `get name() { return this.name; }` If someone tries to get `name`, this code will then try to get `name`. Ie, it calls itself, which calls itself, which calls itself... `set name(value) { /*... */ this.name = value; }`. If someone tries to set `name`, this code will then try to set `name`. Ie, it calls itself, which calls itself, which calls itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
get name() {
    return this.name;
}
```

I believe this act as an infinite recursive function ..
When you call

```
console.log(user.name);
```

It just endlessly call the getter.
Same thing happening for the setter ..

Answer (score 0):

The first class defines `this._name` as a data property.
When the constructor sets `this.name`, it is passed to the Setter, which sets the value of `this._name` to the value. When the getter is called now, it returns the value of `this._name`, which was set by the setter earlier.

The second class only defines a getter and a setter for `this.name`.
When the constructor attemts to set `this.name` to a value, the setter will also try to set `this.name`, which causes the setter to invoked, and the new instance of the setter is attempting to modify `this.name` again, and then the maximum recursion limit is exceeded like this. Same goes for the getter in the second class. It returns `this.name` thereby invoking itself, and this way, it fills up the stack to the maximum recursion limit.